# The MATCH function is not returning correct row number

Tags: excel-formula

I am using excel functions to get the value of y1 by interpolating between two sets of x and y chosen from a list of x and y depending upon the position of desired x1. But the MATCH() function  to determine the upper limit of x1 from the list of x and y is not returning the correct row number. hope you guys got what I am trying to explain and look into the problem.

[image: MATCH() Error]

Expecting a VBA of XLOOKUP as it is not supported in 2016 Office :).

Comment: `=FORCAST(D196,$B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(D196,$A:$A,1)-1),$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(D196,$A:$A,1)-1))`  It is not the match but the offset that is the issue.  Avoid the volatile Offset and use INDEX instead.  Also this assumes that A1 and B1 are numbers.  If they are titles then change the A1 and B1 to A2 and B2 respectively.

Comment: Just used $B:$B and $A:$A instead of fixed array and it worked .
XD